# How we display Treatment_name instead of Treatment_id in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel

I have two table

1. Treatment Table - in this table I have:

```
+--------------+----------------------+
| Treatment_id |    Treatment_name    |
+--------------+----------------------+
|       1      | Bridges              |
|       2      | Root canal Treatment |
|       3      | Filling              |
+--------------+----------------------+
```

2. Fee Table - in this table:

```
+--------+--------------+------+
| Fee_id | Treatment_id | Fee  |
+--------+--------------+------+
|   1    |  1(Bridges)  | 5000 |
|   2    |  2           | 6500 |
+--------+--------------+------+
```

Note: Here `Treatment_id` is `Treatment_name`

Here, i insert data in database then we display data in fee template in laravel
how can display `Treatment_name` instead of `Treatment_id`

pls help i am new in laravel
i want display data fee blade template

Like

```
Fee_id|Treatment_id|Fee
  1     |Bridges|5000
```

instead of `Treatment_id` Display `Treatment_name`
it's work fine 
but when we update Fee table then it display error
it updated but in Fee table Treatment_id column  will updated Treatement_name..
suppose i update above data in Fee table Treatment_id=1=Bridge ,updated it replace   Treatment_name insted of Treatment_id ,so that's why it gives error so,how update

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by Laravel relationships

```
 public function treatment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Treatment::class, 'Treatment_id', 'Treatment_id');
    }
```

**App\Treatment** is Model class

Treatment_id is the fields name that is used to make a relation between the two tables

After this, you can access the treatment table columns in the following way.

```
$fee->treatment->Treatment_name;
```

If you are not aware of Laravel relationships then please read about this.

Here is Laravel Relationship Doc:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: That's work fine but when we update fee table then it show error message Trying to get property 'Treatment_name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\clinic\resources\views\layout\fee-list.blade.php)

Comment: @Abhishekkumar - Can you show some code how actually are you updating a record? It would be helpful to find what is the reason of error?